# Google Sheets - Search two columns and return unique values for all relevant matches

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am making a spreadsheet on Google sheets for my wedding and I am currently creating a guests list page.

I currently have all the information populated into a table with several columns of information and over 100 rows of guest entries.

To the side of the main table housing the guests information I have laid out template for the table plans (I.e. a column with a heading and then 10 rows below it for the relevant guest names to appear) (the first cell that will have a guest name is column L Row 25)

My goal is to have a formula that reads Column H (Table designation) to find rows marked as "Top Table". Once it identified a row that matches, it will then read column B (Name) and return the result of Column B (returning result in the first instance to column L row 25). Each table has 10 guests and so column H will have 10 rows assigned as Top Table with 10 different names appearing in Column B. I can create a formula that returns one name, but I do not know how to get the formula to read past results it has already returned (I.e. returning a unique result each time it runs the formula).

I was wondering would it be possible to have a formula which does the following:

1. Search column H (table designation) for entries marked as "Top Table".
2. When Top Table is identified in column H, review column B (guest name) and extract the name on the same row as the identified Top Table entry.
3. Print that name in the cell containing the formula (in my case the cell I want the name and formula to be in is Column L Row 25).

So far straight forward but this is where I have been unable to progress:

4. Once it has returned the first name in Column L Row 25, I am going to put the same formula in the row below (Column L row 26) and I want the formula to re-run steps 1-3 above but instead of including the same name again, I want it to include the second name identified as "Top Table". And repeat this for 10 iterations as each table bad a maximum of 10 guests.

I know I could just filter column H to see who is assigned where but ideally I do not want to filter this page if possible.

I am open to different approaches to the formula if it achieves the same out come as I am not well versed in formula drafting!

I was only able to get as far as having the first name returned, I was never able to get the formula to return all relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

*Just winging it based on your description. this formula auto-populates upto 10 names, add this formula in `L25` & make sure cells are clear/empty until `L34`:*

```js
=array_constrain(unique(filter(B:B,H:H="Top Table",B:B<>"")),10,1)
```